# How to replace tags first of all transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to replace the tag  with  before starting the rest of the transformation.
I need  instead of  for further transformation.
I tried to convert it via template call. But it didn’t work.
Is there a way to do this first of all in the same stylesheet?

This is my original html document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Text</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contente">
      <p class="t2" name="bookmark1">Text</p>   
      <p>Text</p>
      <p class="t2" name="bookmark2">Text</p>   
      <p>Text<img src=""/></p>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

This is how it should look after the transformation of the tag

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Text</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contente">
      <h2>Text</h2>   
      <p>Text</p>
      <h2>Text</h2>   
      <p>Text<img src=""/></p>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

This is my styleseet

```
<xsl:template name="gen-topic">
  <topic outputclass="konzept" xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/">
  <xsl:call-template name="replaceheadings"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replaceheadings"> 
  <xsl:if test="p[@class='t2']">
    <h2>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|comment()"/>
    </h2>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are showing the exact problem, as in your current XSLT snippet the `gen-topic` template is not getting called anyway. Still, looking purely at your HTML samples, you would probably benefit from using the [XSLT identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

This means you only need to add a template for the `p` tags you wish to transform.

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class='t2']">
        <h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </h2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6L

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake.
I didn’t used the output method.

This helps to fix my problem.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" 
    media-type="text/html" 
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    doctype-system="DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
    cdata-section-elements="script style"
    indent="yes"
    encoding="UTF-8"/>
```